# DataFrame: convert different format of date in df column to same format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a df as below

```
ID     Date
===================
1    1/1/2023
2    2/1/2023
3    2/1/2023
4    31-01-2023
5    31-01-2023
```

All the date mentioned above are for Jan, 2023 and will come in the same format as mentioned above.
I need to convert it to a format **YYYY-MM-DD**.

If i try `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str[:10])`, it makes the 2 and 3rd row data as Feb, 2023.

Comment: add the parameter `dayfirst=True` in the `pd.to_datetime`, with your data sample it works

Comment: Maybe worth noting that these and more complex forms can be converted using the parser in the dateutil module.

Answer (score -1):

```
df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int)
```

you should try this.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This gives for example `20230131` which is not really useful. The OP it looking to convert to datetime/Timestamp not an integer especially as the string has to be correctly converted to datetime before using your code.